# Annotating a queryset with objects from a different "filter" queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

If you're filtering a queryset using values from a different queryset, what is the best way to annotate the "filter" value onto the original queryset?

For example, below I have a simGrants QS that I'm filtering using the simKeys QS. When a match is found, I'd like to append the matching simKeys cosine score to the simGrants object.

The database is fairly large so I'm looking to find the most computationally efficient way to do this.

```
Simkeys =similarity_matrix.objects.filter(y_axis__in=profiles).filter(cosine_score__gt=0)
simGrants = Grant.objects.filter(indexKey__in=simKeys)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *annotate* your `Grant` object with the fields from the related model with an [**`F`**-expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). This results in a query that looks like:

```
from django.db.models import F

Grant.objects.annotate(
    cosine_score=F('similarity_matrix__cosine_score')
).filter(
    similarity_matrix__y_axis__gt=0,
    similarity_matrix__cosine_score__gt=0
)
```

The `Grant` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `cosine_score` that is the `cosine_score` of the related `similarity_matrix` object.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly, I'll have to read up of F-expressions a bit more in the future.